# Difference btw. sendmessage and setting Value

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

What is the difference between those two methods? Why should i prefer one?

1)

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("").GetComponent<Rocket>().active = true;
```

2)

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("").GetComponent<Rocket>().SendMessage("setActive");
```

thanks!

Comment: Avoid `SendMessage`, it's always going to be the slowest possible solution by a large margin (See Heisenbug's answer).  A lot of tutorials use `SendMessage` because it's quick and easy to write up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it seems there are several inconsistencies with your code above:

1) `Components` (and [MonoBehavior](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)) don't have an active property (active belongs to [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)), so the first line of code shouldn't compile. In addition the most recente version of unity don't have active anymore, it's substitued with [activeSelf](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) and [activeInHierarchy](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html).

And btw, both activeSelf and activeInHierarchy are read only, so you can't assing directly a value to them. For changing their value use [SetActive](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) method.

2)
The second line of code shouldn't work either (unless Unity does some magic behind the scenes) because `SetActive` methods belong to `GameObject` and not to your `Rocket` `Component`.

Now, I suppose your question was the difference between:

```
gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

and

```
gameObject.SendMessage("SetActive",true);
```

The result is the same, but in the second way `Unity3D` will use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) to find the proper method to be called, if any. Reflection has an heavy impact on performance, so I suggest you to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Hi Heisenbug, active was a really bad example from my side. active should be any public variable by the object "Rocket". But thank you for giving all the details for active as well. 

But in your example you call the functions, but i would just change the variable value. 

     gameObject.active = true;

So how is the difference now with performance?

Comment: Avoid send message if you have a reference to a component and you can set a value directly or through a method.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message searches through all the components of the gameObject and invokes any function that has the same name as the message. Not a 100% sure but Im sure this uses reflection which is generally considered slow.

SetActive() or the active variable set the gameObject as active or not. If its not active it wont render in the scene and vice versa.